calculate average time from a different table?
I have two tables, Printers and "Printer_audit" where every issue with printer is recorded
I am trying to understand how to calculate the avarage time its taking to fix a printer in general...
assuming each printer has only a single entry of "ISSUE_FOUND" following by a single entry of "FIXED"
while ignoring the ones that are  "TRASHED"  like Xerox3
I know how to calculate the time it took for a single row, but not how to do the average for all Printers
select  (SELECT action_date from
    printer_history where printer_name='Xerox1' and action_name='FIXED')
    -
(SELECT action_date from
    printer_history where printer_name='Xerox1' and action_name='ISSUE_FOUND') diff 
    from dual;

**Update - added issue ID in the Printer_audit table. **
Sample Fiddle:
https://sqlfiddle.com/oracle/online-compiler?id=2c5ffb16-6aad-432d-8bf1-c881cba08356
-- INIT database
CREATE TABLE printer (
  printerID INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  Name VARCHAR2(100) 
);
-- INIT history
CREATE TABLE printer_history (
  IssueId INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  printer_name VARCHAR2(100), 
  action_name VARCHAR2(100),
  action_date TIMESTAMP  
);
INSERT INTO printer(Name) VALUES ('Xerox1');
INSERT INTO printer(Name) VALUES ('Xerox2');
INSERT INTO printer(Name) VALUES ('Xerox3');

INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox1','INSTALLED'  , TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:44:00.743000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox1','ISSUE_FOUND', TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:45:00.744000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox1','FIXED'      , TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-15 8:33:00.655000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );

INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox2','INSTALLED'  , TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-08-01 05:11:00.722000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox2','ISSUE_FOUND', TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-09-02 03:44:00.732000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox2','FIXED'      , TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-09-14 07:55:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );

INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox3','INSTALLED'  , TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-08-01 05:11:00.752000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox3','ISSUE_FOUND'  , TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-08-05 05:11:00.752000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );
INSERT INTO printer_history(printer_name,action_name,action_date) VALUES ('Xerox3','TRASHED'  , TO_TIMESTAMP('2018-08-23 05:11:00.752000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') );

select * from printer_history;

-- QUERY database

select  (SELECT action_date from
    printer_history where printer_name='Xerox1' and action_name='FIXED')
    -
(SELECT action_date from
    printer_history where printer_name='Xerox1' and action_name='ISSUE_FOUND') diff 
    from dual;


There's no IssueID?  What happens if you have two different problems with the same printer at the same time?

There is Issue_id if its relevant / helpful ... , same printer at the same time - I can ignore that.

I don't think you can ignore it.  If there are two concurrent issues on the same printer, and no issue ID , this report may not be possible.  If there can't be concurrent issues, it is possible.  But if there's an issue ID that provides different options for developing the query.

ok thank you so much! Edited it to have issue ID

If the IssueId column is an identity column, there is a different value on every row in the table.  It identifies a row on the table, not a specific issue.  So if that's truly the structure, IssueId is irrelevant to this question.

Ohh sorry!  i don't have a way to identify a specific issue , its just a matter of finding the first "FIXED" after "ISSUE_FOUND"

You say you want the average time to fix an issue.  Please provide the time increment (months, hours, etc.).

You say there can be only one 'ISSUE_FOUND' and one 'FIXED' per printer. This is a bit strange, considering that we are looking at a "printer_history", but it makes the issue quite easy.
The only problem (at least in Oracle 11 which you tagged the request with) is that you cannot apply AVG on intervals (the result when subtracting one timestamp from another), unfortunately.
Instead cast the timestamps to datetimes (in Oracle inappropriately called DATE). Then you get the durations as fractions of days:
with
  issue_found as
  (
    select * 
    from printer_history
    where action_name = 'ISSUE_FOUND'
  ),
  fixed as
  (
    select * 
    from printer_history
    where action_name = 'FIXED'
  ),
  durations as
  (
    select cast(f.action_date as date) - cast(if.action_date as date) as diff
    from issue_found if
    join fixed f using (printer_name)
  )
select round(avg(diff), 1) as days
from durations;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/p62dU2ux

How well will that work if a printer had more than one issue over its lifespan?

Oh, I see.  You addressed that in your answer.  There can be only one.

@dougp: Yep, they say there can be only one issue per printer. It wouldn't be too difficult to extend this to multiple issues per printer though. Just add a ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY printer_name ORDER BY action_date) AS rn to the first two queries and include the rn in the USING clause. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/G_9ET1tA

From Oracle 12, you can use MATCH_RECOGNIZE to perform row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT COALESCE(printer_name, 'All printers') AS printer_name,
       AVG(CAST(fixed_date AS DATE) - CAST(found_date AS DATE))
         AS avg_fix_time_in_days
FROM   printer_history
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY printer_name
         ORDER BY action_date
         MEASURES
           issue_found.action_date AS found_date,
           fixed.action_date       AS fixed_date
         PATTERN ( issue_found other*? fixed )
         DEFINE
           issue_found AS action_name = 'ISSUE_FOUND',
           fixed       AS action_name = 'FIXED'
       )
GROUP BY ROLLUP(printer_name)

In earlier versions, you can use the LAG analytic function:
SELECT COALESCE(printer_name, 'All printers') AS printer_name,
       AVG(CAST(action_date AS DATE) - CAST(found_date AS DATE))
         AS avg_fix_time_in_days
FROM   (
  SELECT printer_name,
         action_name,
         LAG(CASE action_name WHEN 'ISSUE_FOUND' THEN action_date END)
           IGNORE NULLS OVER (
             PARTITION BY printer_name ORDER BY action_date
           ) AS found_date,
         action_date
  FROM   printer_history
  WHERE  action_name IN ('ISSUE_FOUND', 'FIXED')
)
WHERE  action_name = 'FIXED'
GROUP BY ROLLUP(printer_name)

Note: Printers can have multiple issues and this will calculate the average time for each printer and globally over all the relevant issues.
Which, for the sample data, both output:



PRINTER_NAME
AVG_FIX_TIME_IN_DAYS




Xerox1
13.075


Xerox2
12.17430555555555555555555555555555555556


All printers
12.62465277777777777777777777777777777778



fiddle
